# finding minimum and maximum of a function at given intervals

Tags: calculus, derivatives

here is the question:

[image]

here is the correct answer:

(-1, 7/2)

My working:

I know that by plugging in 0 into the equation you get -1 but I don't understand how to get  7/2

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(x) = -2(x-\frac32)^2 + \frac72$.  So the maximum is when the quadratic term is zero.

Comment: where did 3/2 come from?

Comment: That's needed to complete the square. Try a few exercises in that, you will get good at finding the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Apply the [second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test) to get minima/maxima of the function. Don't forget to check the boundaries of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need derivatives at all.  The only candidates for min and max are clearly $0$, $2$ and $3/2$.